# JQuery Keyup event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, keyup

So, I need use this event so I can navigate trought blog posts. I use the 'J' key to go to the previous post and the 'K' key to go to the next post.
My problem is that the event works on the first try but then doesn't work anymore. 
When i restart the browser it works if i press J or K and it redirects me to the previous/next post. But then if I press again it does nothing.

Sorry if I can't explain it exactly enought and thanks for helping.

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 74) {
      var left_link = $('#nav-left a').attr('href');
      alert(left_link);
      if(typeof left_link !== 'undefined' && left_link !== false)
        window.location = left_link;
   } 
   else if (event.keyCode == 75) {
     var right_link = $('#nav-right a').attr('href');
     alert(right_link);
     if(typeof right_link !== 'undefined' && right_link !== false)
       window.location = right_link;
   }
});
```

Even if I don't do the redirect and only those alerts it doesn't work.

Comment: is this script included on the pages that your code redirects to?

Comment: the alerts don't work either on the second keyup?

Comment: the alert doesn't work either and yes, the script is included on the pages where i make the redirect

Comment: Just as an FYI, `left_link` will always be `undefined`, `null` or a string, never the Boolean value `false`, so that last check in your if conditional will always evaluate `true`. You could probably just use `if (left_link && left_link.length !== 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with the script loading, I applied a delay of 1 second and now it works just fine.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Adding a delay is a poor choice: you don't always know how long the delay will be to load the script. Use the jQuery(document).ready() method to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

After you've changed the location, a new document is loaded. A document without a listener for keyup events.